# Отправка измененных данных

Tags: jquery, json, php, ui

Здравствуйте, вопрос по UI фреймворку Kendo UI c виджетом [Grid](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing.html) , вопрос в следующем, начинаю редактировать данные, и следом отправляю их в файл обработчик, но не могу словить содержимое переменой, то есть в файле должен принять типа такого запроса $_REQUEST['data'], как узнать какая переменная с данными приходит что бы дальше с ней работать?

Comment: @dogmar, по дивным и не часто используемым фреймворкам мало кто вам, *наверное*, ответит. Переформулируйте вопрос на более общий.

Comment: Думаю дело даже не во фреймворке, на страничке отправляется jsonp запрос, мне нужно просто благополучно принять его, сам я незнаю под каким названием он шлеться, т.к. в js только учусь, думаю если знающие js'ники пощупают код Увидят какой запрос шлется в файл :) Если нет, то буду как нибуть переформулировать.

Comment: @dogmar, ну вот видите - можетеже описать проблему. Ждём изменения вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень предлагаю воспользоваться firebug'om или google chrome которые отлично показывают xhr запросы ;)

Comment: подскажите слепому где?

Comment: Проинспектировать элемент -> Network, там я вижу отправляемые запросы,ну и получаю ответы.

Comment: ну либо из меню (в хроме) -- Инструменты - Инструменты разработчика - Сеть. внизу можно фильтр выставить, чтобы только xhr запросы показывалось, а не все подряд.

FireBug для FireFox -- плагин, там все аналогично.